# How to provision a AWS cloud 9 environment?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloud9

I need to provision a cloud 9 environment and run some provision scripts in it. Tried to do it with cloudFormation but found no way to ssh into it (without accessing the cloud9 terminal) nor to pass a script while bring cloud9 up.

My goal: setup several cloud nine instances for a workshop, which needs to run some scripts to work with it.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-configuration is still a weak point for Cloud9 instances. What I've seen others do is create a script that is distributed to users and then ask them to run it in the terminal to setup the environment - not ideal but it works. I too would like to see a solution using CloudFormation or some other mechanism. Does this help?

Comment: Thx for your response. You mean they have "setup-script" in their repository to let the users execute it in the c9 terminal?

Comment: Yes - exactly. You'll need to share the repo.

Comment: ... Or at least share the script that you want to run somehow. Sorry that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Cloud9 attach to any server via ssh after installing a few utilities.  Thus, you can use whatever provisioning tools you want as long as your process includes adding those utilities.